# How do you repair an unfinished update

Tags: package-management, updates, login

An update froze midway, and now I cannot login to my desktop. I have no experience with this scenario and am new to Ubuntu in general.

I used <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F1</kbd> to get into a terminal at the login screen, I just don't know how to identify the broken update and repair it.

If this is not possible, there is just one folder I need from my hard drive before I can reformat. Perhaps it may be easier for me to take this route, and just save this file to a USB, then reformat, as I am not experienced with terminal commands.

Comment: What command did you run to perform update?

Comment: It prompted me to do the automatic update while I was performing another task, then froze.

Answer (score 1):

If you can login to terminal as you say try to run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure -a` and then `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` this should repair broken dependencies and update packages after interrupted update.

Comment: I've received an error: requested operation requires superuser privilege. I got a lot of "failed to fetch" errors as well when doing the second command line that you pasted.

Comment: Is your computer connected to internet? Where did you get first error?

Comment: Try to boot in safe mode with internet .

Comment: I've done a second attempt after checking my connection, and have successfully repaired the software. Many thanks Honza!